# visual studio code saving file in another directory than script

Tags: python, pandas, file, visual-studio-code

When I execute below python code in visual studio, it saves file to `"C:\Users\username"`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([0]*2)
df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

How I can change setting, so that it will always save to directory where code is saved ?

Any work around ?

Thanks.

Comment: provide the path where your code is saved while saving the df to csv :- `df.to_csv('C:\path_of_code\results.csv', index=False, header=False)`

Comment: Hi, I am using many "relative paths" in my code and changing all of them to "full paths " is time consuming... Any work around other than using "full paths" ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to define your path where you intend to write , use this:

Specify the path by : `myDir = '/path/to/Desktop/My_project_folder'`
then you can join this using `os.path.join` :

```
output_path = os.path.join(myDir, 'result.csv')
```

Similarly you could define other paths too.

You can find the path to file by :

```
import os
print (os.path.abspath("testfile.ext"))
```

This gives the absolute path, to get the full path use:

```
for r,d,f in os.walk("C:\\"):
for files in f:
     if files == "testfile.ext":
        print (os.path.join(r,files))
```

output:

```
C:\path\testfile.ext
```